# Trying to resolve: Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide virtual/kernel

Tags: linux, yocto

In this error the yocto system mentions that I have 2 .bb files that provide the same thing. How do I show what each of the .bb files provide? I'm assuming that there are several layers of indirection here since examining the .bb files does not appear to tell you anything about what it provides other than its actual name.

In this case I've created (using yocto-bsp) my own BSP layer which right now only has the custom linux kernel defined in it and as version 3.14. When I build (bitbake virtual/kernel) it ends up building both the 3.19 and my 3.14 kernel.

Cheers!!

Comment: Have you set `PREFERRED_RPOVIDER_virtual/kernel` and "PREFERRED_VERSION_<your-custom-linux>` in your machine config?

Comment: Yes indeed this has been done.

Comment: Could you run  ` bitbake virtual/kernel -e | grep PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel` just to verify that it's being set correctly. Could you also show us the value of  ` COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` in your own kernel recipe?

Comment: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel="linux-yocto-custom" and the value for COMPATIBLE_MACHINE is blank

Comment: That's wrong, my settings for COMPATIBLE_MACHINE is
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_broadwell-sled = "broadwell-sled"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_genericx86 = "genericx86"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_genericx86-64 = "genericx86-64"

Comment: Is there a better forum to get answers about yocto? I have not been able to find any kind of actual support except on here and it's pretty low on here.

Comment: Well, to go back to a post of the original question, it's kernel.bbclass that had the `PROVIDES` for `virtual/kernel`. If you're still seeing the warning about multiple providers, that's strange, as having a correct `PREFERRED_PROVIDER` should take care of that. The normal support forum for Yocto Project, is yocto@yoctoproject.org, or one of the other mailing lists at yoctoproject.org out openembedded.org, depending on which layer the question is about.